# Back Button not work when load page using history.pushState in JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, windows, pushstate, popstate

I am trying to load a page via ajax with `history.pushState` and page load successfully, but the back button does not work in this case. Please check my code below:

```
function processAjaxData(response, urlPath){
    document.write(response)
    document.title = '';
    window.history.pushState({"html":response,"pageTitle":''},"", urlPath);
}

$('#apply_loader').click(function(e){
   
      var nextPage = $(this).attr('href');
      $.get(nextPage,  // url
      function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  // success callback
        processAjaxData(data,nextPage);
      }
    );
});
```

I am trying to use `popstate` below to identify a back button click.

```
  $(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
    console.log('asd');
     location.reload();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late, but perhaps this will fix the problem:

Instead of location.reload(), try:

`window.location = location.href`